# How to avoid duplicating function call in the IF check and return statement if the condition evaluates to true?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a function `process`. If attempts to retrieve one of name, address, phone from the input data (in that order) using their own functions which either return the appropriate value or return ''. If all return '' then return the data as it is.

Following is the code, is there a better way to avoid duplicating function invocations in both if check and return?

```
def process(data):
  if get_name(data):
    return get_name(data)
  elif get_address(data):
    return get_address(data)
  elif get_phone(data):
    return get_phone(data)
  return data
```

Comment: If you are on Python 3.8+ you can use walrus `:=` operator

Comment: 1. What's wrong with saving the return value into a variable, checking if it ISN'T equal to ''. If all return '' and if that's true then returning that value?
2. Since equating two strings is bad, could you change the "null" return value of get_name/get_address/etc... into a "False"?

Comment: @Omrii - Regarding point 2 - return value is not null, it is ''; which also means false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code logic, you can write it like this. The `or` sequence will return the first positive data, in other words the data that is `truthy`.

```
def process(data):
    name = get_name(data)
    address = get_address(data)
    phone = get_phone(data):
    return name or address or phone or data
```

Comment: Or simply `return get_name(data) or get_address(data) or get_phone(data) or data`

Answer (score 1):

You can use walrus operator `:=` if you use python 3.8+

```py
def process(data):
  if name:=get_name(data):
    return name
  elif address := get_address(data):
    return address
  elif phone := get_phone(data):
    return phone
  return data
```